# Make a GROUP_CONCAT to row groups without repeating the grouped rows induvidually

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to GROUP_CONCAT some results that are already grouped, but I'm getting concatenated the previously grouped rows.

Let's say I have a Table of Persons. Each person has a list of products they bought.

Customer:

```
+-------+---------+
| name  | comment |
+-------+---------+
| David | Hey!    |
| Joe   | Bye!    |
| John  | Hey!    |
+-------+---------+
```

Product:

```
+-------+----------+----------+
| name  | customer | category |
+-------+----------+----------+
| Apple | David    | Food     |
| Melon | David    | Food     |
| Pizza | John     | Food     |
| Pizza | David    | Food     |
| Water | Joe      | Drink    |
+-------+----------+----------+
```

I need to get the comments of all customers that bought food or drink.

So I JOIN the tables and I get:

```
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+
| product.name | customer.name | customer.comment | product.category |
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+
| Apple        | David         | Hey!             | Food             |
| Melon        | David         | Hey!             | Food             |
| Pizza        | John          | Hey!             | Food             |
| Pizza        | David         | Hey!             | Food             |
| Water        | Joe           | Bye!             | Drink            |
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Now, to get rid of duplicate customers I make a `GROUP BY customer.name` and I get:

```
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+
| product.name | customer.name | customer.comment | product.category |
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+
| Apple        | David         | Hey!             | Food             |
| Pizza        | John          | Hey!             | Food             |
| Water        | Joe           | Bye!             | Drink            |
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+
```

At this point, I expect to make a `GROUP BY` category, concatenating the comments.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(customer.comment) AS 'comments' FROM Customer c JOIN Product p ON c.name = p.name group by product.category.
```

This query returns:

```
+----------------+------------------+
|    comments    | product.category |
+----------------+------------------+
| Hey!,Hey!,Hey! | Food             |
| Bye!           | Drink            |
+----------------+------------------+
```

As you can see, the "Hey!" of David is duplicated, what I expect is this result:

```
+-----------+------------------+
| comments  | product.category |
+-----------+------------------+
| Hey!,Hey! | Food             |
| Bye!      | Drink            |
+-----------+------------------+
```

Note that David and John have the same comment text. I did this in purpose because I don't want to fix this duplicity with a `distinct`, as I do want repeated comments if they come from different customers.

Is there a way to apply the concat AFTER the grouping without subquerying? I feel like it is using the comments before they were grouped by customer name...

Comment: @Strawberry There's no application. I need to extract it this way from the database. Of course this is easy with code, but please, understand that this can be a valid problem to solve.

Comment: I'm unconvinced. To my mind, there is no problem in sql for which GROUP_CONCAT need form part of the solution.

Comment: Seriously, are you looking for solution for all there different databases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider the query as `your_query` which you have mentioned as

> Now, to get rid of duplicate customers I make a GROUP BY customer.name
> and I get

Then use it in from subquery as follows:

```
Select SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(comment) AS 'comments', category
  FROM (your_query) t
 Group by category;
```

Comment: So the only way is with a subquery, right? I thought I was missing something that would run in a simple query.

Comment: Seeing at your requirement, yes sub-query seems the only option